# How do I serve a static HTML at API endpoint using Rocket?

Tags: html, web, rust, static, rocket

I want to serve a simple HTML file as a response to a request to an API endpoint like `/` or `api/`. The only thing I have managed to find online is how to host the a static file as `/index.html` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve a single file from a route by returning [`NamedFile`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/fs/struct.NamedFile.html):

```
use rocket::fs::NamedFile;
use rocket::get;

#[get("/api")]
async fn serve_home_page() -> Result<NamedFile, std::io::Error> {
    NamedFile::open("index.html").await
}
```

This is the 0.5 API; if you're using 0.4 then change the import to `rocket::response::NamedFile` and remove the `async`/`await` syntax. You can also return a simple `std::fs::File` or `tokio::fs::File`, but the `NamedFile` will do the extra step of setting the correct `Content-Type` header based on the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sth relevant in the `Templates` in both [guides](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/responses/#templates) and [examples](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/master/examples/templating). I think this might be what you need.